# Converting An Integer to a Byte (for PySerial, using Python25)

Tags: python, python-2.5

This seems like it should be simple, but I haven't been able to figure it out...

I'm trying to use [PySerial](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/pyserial_api.html) to communicate with a microcontroller.  I want to send an index location, but when I send it, it PySerial sends the ASCII of the number (so when I send a 0, it sends 48).

I know for Python26 and up, I would just enclose the number with the built-in bytes function like so:

```
self.index = bytes([index])
```

However, Python25 doesn't have that function. I can't find any documentation suggesting an equivalent. Does anybody know what I should do?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Sorry, here's a simplified version of my code...

```
class SecondaryImage():
    def __init__(self, index):
        self.index = index
    def sendIndex(self):
        serial.write(self.index)

for i in range(64):
    img = SecondaryImage(i)
    imgs.append(img)
```

And then I'd call sendIndex() seperately--

```
imgs[2].sendIndex()
```

Comment: Show your code.  It sounds like you have extra quotes turning numbers into strings.

Comment: That doesn't even run, it throws a `TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)`.  Just change the initialization to `img = SecondaryImage(i)` without the `self`.

Comment: Oh, yea, sorry--that was a casualty to my attempt to strip the extraneous elements of my code. SecondaryImage usually takes more parameters, but I left the non-relevant bits out. I forgot to take that 'self' out in the for loop! Again, sorry about that.

Comment: For reference: the Python 3.1 documentation on `bytes` is at http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#bytes ; there does not appear to be any documentation for that in 2.x, but see the important note in the PySerial documentation here http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/pyserial_api.html#serial.to_bytes .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`chr` is built-in which will you the character for the ordinal you send.

Answer (score 1):

Serial communicates in ascii, so you want to use `chr` to convert numbers to their ascii character equivalents.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the binascii module?

http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.4/lib/module-binascii.html